# Can I add a method to a requirejs module used as dependency in another module and have it available every time the module is loaded as dependency?

Tags: javascript, module, dependencies, requirejs

If I have a module like this:

```
define([
   'app'
  , 'text!index.html!strip'
  , 'css!index'
  ],
  function (App, source) {
    var response = {};

    App.newMethod = function (foo) {
      console.log("foo ="+foo);
    };

  // return response object
  return response;
  }
);
```

I'm wondering how to add methods to a module that is used as a dependency in another module. Sure I can add methods to the object, but will these also update the `App` object when it is called from another module?

**Question**:
Is there a way to add methods to a module, which is loaded as a dependency and have these methods available on all modules, which require this dependency?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Short answer:

Yes. The module needs to be an object/instance (not a class) and it will work with requirejs.

### Long answer:

When you require a module as a dependence for the first time Requirejs generates an object, and for the next times you requires the module Requirejs will return the object it generated the first time. So all the times you require a module you get always the same reference of the object.

With

```
define([], function () {
    var app =  {
        //my methods.
    };

    return app;
});
```

and

```
define(['app'], function (app) {
    app.newMethod = function (){
        // ...
    };
});
```

you can use app like this:

```
define(['app'], function (app) {
    app.newMethod();
});
```

But injecting methods from one object to an other is a really bad practice. If you need something from an object just add it when creating the object, not by injection.

```
define([], function () {
    var app =  {
        newMethod: function () {
            // ...
        },
        // my methods.
    };

    return app;
});
```

For example if object `A` injects a new method that will be used in object `B`, but `B` is called when `A` is not loaded then there would be an error `Object #<Object> has no method 'newMethod'`

Comment: Thanks. Very nice answer! I also understand it's bad practice, but plucking `App` on `window.App` also is and my application needs a number of configuration modules, which all expose some methods that should be available to be called by other modules. In the above case, I have a translation gadget/module, which requires some `App.settings` information to retrieve the language to set the application to. When set, it exposes the `App.translate()` method, so other modules can "translate themselves" if needed. Not really sure how to do this nicely, when trying to keep things separated during init.

Comment: The best option you have is to use directly the translation module and not the app: `translation.translate();`. If this is not an option you can namespace it: `app.translation.translate()`. If isn't an aoption you can reduce the problems by creating an empty translate method in the app and then give it the logic from the translation module.

Comment: Or why doesn't the app require all the modules and it adds itself the functions it nedds based on the data returned by the configuration modules? For example make the config modules return a map with the name of the method and the method so app knows what to add and with what name.

Comment: mh. Need to think about both suggestions. My translation module is added based on source-code, so the first time a page displays a "translation-button", I'm loading the underlying module (and html template) via require. So it's not really tied to my app-module, which sets up the application and global handlers only. But I like both ideas. I had used `window.App.translate` initially, so `App.translate` will be just fine. And better than depending all modules on `translate`